# How to POST form parameters?

Tags: jetty

I'm trying to send HTTP POST form parameters. I know the Content-Type has to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and parameters must be encoded in the request body.

[In version 9.0.6](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.6.v20130930/http-client-api.html), Jetty seems to have done this automatically:

> The POST request is sent with the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type, and POST parameter values are automatically URL-encoded.

But [in version 9.4.19](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.19.v20190610/http-client-api.html), I see the documentation has changed and now it says:

> The POST parameter values added via the param() method are automatically URL-encoded.

Sure enough, invoking:

```
httpClient.POST("http://example.com/entity/1")
        .param("p", "value")
        .send();
```

Now treats the parameters as URL query parameters. Nothing gets added to the request body.

What is the correct way to properly POST form parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTML Form is body content on a POST request.

So that means you have to use the `org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.ContentProvider`, and [`Request.content(ContentProvider)`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/client/api/Request.html#content(org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.ContentProvider)) API.

There's 2 `ContentProvider` implementations for working with HTML Forms.

### FormContentProvider

- class: [`org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FormContentProvider`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/FormContentProvider.html)
- content-type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FormContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.Fields;


Fields fields = new Fields();
fields.put("fruit", "apple");
httpClient.POST("http://example.com/entity/1")
    .content(new FormContentProvider(fields))
    .send();
```

### MultiPartContentProvider

- class: [`org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.MultiPartContentProvider`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/MultiPartContentProvider.html)
- content-type: `multipart/form-data`

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.MultiPartContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.StringContentProvider;

MultiPartContentProvider multiPart = new MultiPartContentProvider();
multiPart.addFieldPart("fruit", new StringContentProvider("apple"), null);
multiPart.close();
httpClient.POST("http://example.com/entity/1")
    .content(multiPart)
    .send();
```